# How to center TabBarItem - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabbar

How can I position my TabBarIcon in the middle? It should be placed on top of this red circle. [image: Screenshot]

My code for the red circle:

```
let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
let itemBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: tabBarItemSize.width / 2, y: 35, width: 6, height: 6))
itemBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .red
itemBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
tabBar.addSubview(itemBackgroundView)
```

How can I center my TabBarIcon, or how can you calculate where that Icon is located?

Comment: Position in the middle of what?

Comment: Of the tab. It should be above the red circle.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/itempositioning

Comment: Yep, I've tried that. It doesn't work. What if instead of putting it in the center, you just have to calculate where the icon is located, but how?

Comment: Maybe subclass UITabBarItem and do your own drawing.

Comment: You can try to use `imageInsets` of `UITabBarItem`

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `imageInsets` of `UITabBarItem`, as below code:

```
let items = tabBarCnt.tabBar.items
for item in items!
{
   item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: `for item in items!` is bad practice and could potentially cause a crash. Better to use `if let items = tabBar.items { for item in items { ... } } `